# Probability Counting$ (n-1)!/n!$

Tags: probability

Probability of getting $1$ in a dice throw is $1/6$ by intuition, however it is also true that $5!/6! = 1/6$. I could not understand why this true and $(n-1)!/n! = 1/n$.

But the same will not be true if I choose $4$ out of $ n$ saying that $(n-4)!/n! = 4/n$ ?

Please help me in understanding this concept.

Comment: $n!=1\times 2\times 3\times 3\cdots \times (n-1)\times n$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{(n-4)!}{n!} =\frac{1}{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)} $$

So, first things first - do you understand why your assertion about $\frac{(n-4)!}{n!}$ is wrong?

---

Incase this was an issue, you can expand a factorial in the following way:

$n!=n(n-1)!=n(n-1)(n-2)!...$

Also, you're thinking about the probability of obtaining a 1 or a 4 in an incorrect way. Because a dice is fair and each number is represented only once, then the probability of obtaining any number on a dice is given by the inverse of the number of sample points in the sample space. This is why  you have $\frac{1}{6}$ of a chance of rolling a 1 and the exact same chance of rolling a 2,3,4,5 or 6.

I had a bit of trouble interpreting your question. I hope this is what you need. If not, let me know and I will gladly change this answer.

Comment: What is inverse of the number of sample points in the sample space?

Comment: There are six sides to a normal dice. Each side of that dice has one number [1,6] where each number is represented only once. Then we can roll a dice and obtain six different outcomes, correct? Since the dice is fair we can then assume that the probability of rolling any number is equal to $\frac{1}{6}$ which is the inverse of the number of possible outcomes.

Comment: Probably I understood. We are taking 6! because these are the total no of outcome possible if we roll that 6 times. Then we divide 5! by 6! because once we roll the dice we are not going to receive any five of the outcome which could happen in 5! ways. Now probably of getting any number is nothing but Total possible ways of getting 5! divided by Total possible ways 6!.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine $n=6$.

$$\frac{5*4*3*2*1}{6*5*4*3*2*1}=\frac{1}{6}$$

Do you see why?

Answer (score 0):

For $$\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}$$Let $n=6$ $$\frac{1*2*3*4*5}{1*2*3*4*5*6} = \frac{1}{6} = \frac{\frac{1}{1}}{6}$$ as $$  \frac{\color{red}{1*2*3*4*5}}{\color{red}{1*2*3*4*5}} = \frac{1}{1} \implies \frac{\color{red}{1*2*3*4*5}}{\color{red}{1*2*3*4*5}*6} = \frac{\frac{1}{1}}{6} = \frac{1}{6}$$